# Retornar div a posição inicial após animação?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Como posso fazer para retornar minha `div` à posição inicial caso ela chegue a um determinado ponto à esquerda? Tenho o seguinte código atual:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $("#botao").click(function() {      
        $(".maior").animate({left:"-=400px"},1000)
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.maior {
    width: 1614px;
    height: 433px;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bolder;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 9px;
    top: -4px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A propriedade jQuery [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) nada mais faz do que criar um atributo `style` no seu elemento HTML e trocar o seu valor de forma gradual. Sendo assim, se você remover este atributo após a animação, o elemento volta ao seu local inicial.

Você poderia fazer o seguinte:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $("#botao").click(function() {        
          $(".maior").animate({left:"-=400px"},1000,function(){
              $(this).removeAttr('style');
          });
    });
});
```

O que eu fiz acima foi adicionar um *callback* que dispara sempre que a animação termina, e dentro desse *callback* eu simplesmente removo o atributo `style` do elemento que foi animado.

Exemplo: [**`FIDDLE`**](http://jsfiddle.net/w25Aj/)

Comment: Outra possibilidade é de utilizar outro `animate` dentro da função do primeiro, como por exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/w25Aj/3/

Comment: Bem pensado @Marciano.Andrade desta forma fica até mais suave a transição de volta.

Comment: O problema é que isso não satisfaz a necessidade do OP, visto que ele quer que o elemento volte ao local ao atingir um determinado ponto.

Comment: Ou pelo visto não, não entendi agora

Comment: deu algum erro com o código do @Sergio, com o outro retorna, porém não verifica a posição.

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar o [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/), esse método tem 2 parâmetros. O primeiro é para limpar a lista de animações em espera, o segundo é para ir para a posição final. No seu caso pretende `.stop(true, false);`

Pode usar a função complete para verificar a posição final, mas também pode verificar logo no inicio do click (usando o `.stop()`) e assim não correr o animate, ou mudar-lhe o valor para o seu máximo à esquerda.

Sugestão (com muitas variáveis para ser mais claro:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#botao").click(function () {
        var maior = $(".maior");
        var limite = 200; // o seu valor limite aqui
        var posicao Atual = maior.position().left;
        var deslocamento = 400; // o deslocamento padrão
        if (posicao <= limite){ // caso esteja já no limite
            maior.stop(true, false);
            return;
        };
        // na linha de baixo verifica se o deslocamento padrão faz com que 
        // vá demasiado à esquerda, e nesse caso compensa o deslocamento
        if (posicao - 400 < limite) deslocamento = limite - posicao;
        maior.animate({
            left: "-=" + deslocamento + "px"
        }, 1000)
    });
});
```